# Java access to protected member in subclass in different package, using object reference of parent type

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, protected

I have the following code in two separate files.

```
package animal;

public class Frog
{
    protected void ribbit()
    {
        System.out.println("In Frog class!");
    }
}





package other;

import animal.*;

public class Tadpole extends Frog

{
    protected void ribbit()
    {
        System.out.println("In Tadpole class!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tadpole t = new Tadpole();
        t.ribbit();

        Frog f = new Tadpole();
        f.ribbit(); // Does not compile
    }
}
```

The first `Tadpole` object assigned to `Tadpole` type obviously compiles fine and the call to `ribbit()` will be to the `Tadpole`'s `ribbit()` implementation. The second `Tadpole` object that is created and assigned to a `Frog` reference. However, the call to `ribbit()` results in a compiler error.

I know that if you create a subclass object in the subclass and assign to a superclass reference that is outside of the subclass's package and try to call a superclass method, this is not allowed. But in this case, shouldn't polymorphism make the object reference "f" call the `Tadpole`'s `ribbit()` method since a `Tadpole` object was assigned to it? Why does this cause a compiler error and why is this is not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to the rules about access to `protected` class members. See [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2) from the Java Language Specification on details, specifically:

> Let C be the class in which a `protected` member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if *Id* denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> - If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id or a method reference expression Q :: Id (§15.13), where Q is an ExpressionName, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S.
> - **If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, or a method invocation expression E.Id(...), or a method reference expression E :: Id, where E is a Primary expression (§15.8), then the access is permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S**.

So within the body of a subclass of `Frog`, you can only access `x.ribbit()` if `x` is a *subclass* of `Frog` (`x` cannot be declared a `Frog`).

This restriction exists on `protected` members, because otherwise, imagine that `Frog` has a protected `int` field:

```
public class Frog {
    protected int a = 1;

    ...
}
```

Then one would be able to define a `public` method in the subclass of `Frog`:

```
public class TadPole extends Frog {

    public int revealFieldValueOfParent(Frog frog) {
        return frog.a;  // imagine this was OK
    }
}
```

Then any other (unrelated) class would be able to access the field by passing a `Frog` to the method of the subclass:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         TadPole tadpole = new TadPole();
         Frog frog = new Frog();
         int revealedValue = tadpole.revealFieldValueOfParent(frog);
         // print revealedValue
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This compiler error has nothing to do with polymorphism. Polymorphism, as related to the actual type of the object, is a runtime aspect and the compiler does not try to think whether at runtime the variable `f` actually refers to a `Frog` or to a `Tadpole`. All the compiler is doing here is enforcing the rules of the `protected` modifier, nothing more.

**EDIT 2:**

Based on the comments below, the `revealFieldValueOfParent(Frog frog)` method would actually *reveal* the value of the `protected` if we change it to `revealFieldValue(TadPole frog)`, but you can also do that revealing trick with private members (i.e. similar to a getter method). It would really become the responsibility of the subclass to know what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks @manouti. Do you know the reasoning behind this rule? What were the creators of Java intending with this?

Comment: @CodeMonkey This should be marked as the correct answer :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @manouti, that explains why Java was designed like that with respect to the rule you posted. Please see my answer to this question on this post and see if you agree with my explanation for this question. I believe it has to do with Frog not being a subclass of Tadpole actually.

Comment: we can reveal the value by just changing reference type 

public class TadPole extends Frog {
    public int revealFieldValueOfParent(TadPole frog) {
        return frog.a;  // still we can do this
    }
}

Comment: @OmerGillani But you can also do that revealing trick with `private` members (i.e. similar to a getter method). It would really become the responsibility of the subclass `TadPole` to know what it's doing. There is always a way to shoot one's self in the foot, if one wants to.

Comment: @AR.3 No, we can't reveal parent class private members in child class.

Comment: @OmerGillani You're right. My last comment was a complete miss... But still, I would argue that exposing a `protected` member declared in the parent class, from within the subclass and in the form `subclassVariable.protectedField` is the responsibility of the subclass.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I didn't understand why it's working for package private accessor,in fact, package private has not this resctriction even if it has the same problematic, which is the possibility that any other  class of an unrelated package would be able to access the field by passing the reference to a public method. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` limits access to `Class`, `package`, or subclass as long as the subclass is declared as type of subclass and not the superclass.

e.g. if `Frog` and `Tadpole` are in different `packages`, `Frog f = new Tadpole();` does not work if you want to access `Frog`'s `ribbit` method, but `Tadpole f = new Tadpole();` does

Comment: Protected also allows sub classes access @CodeMonkey but does not allow access to other packages

Comment: I am able to compile the code if they are either in the same `package` or if `Frog`'s `ribbit` is declared as `public`

Comment: "The protected access modifier is accessible within package and outside the package but through inheritance only." In this case, it is through inheritance because Tadpole extends Frog.

http://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers

Comment: @nLee, the code will compile if they are in the same package or if ribbit is public. However, this question is for the particular case where ribbit() is protected and the classes are in separate packages and the ribbit() method is being called on a superclass reference with a subclass object assigned to it.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Yes but Tadpole and Frog are in different packages. See more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @Turtle "The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: My apologies, I take back my comment. I sent a link without fully reading it

Comment: @nLee. "A class that is derived from another class is called a subclass (also a derived class, extended class, or child class)" Tadpole extends Frog and is a subclass. However, I think I figured out why it doesn't compile. We may have the same idea but I am unable to understand which things you are saying are not accessible with respect to what.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: @CodeMonkey No, I had it mistaken at first and did not realize until I read into it a bit further

Answer (score 1):

Just for simple understanding, method overriding is runtime feature . This is obtained in run time and compiler do not care about this during compilation. So your code has to be compiler compliance . So your compilation fails because the method is not accessible from other package during compilation ( despite the fact that it would be available during run time as it inherits the Frog class).

Answer (score 0):

Protected Access Modifier - Variables, methods and constructors which are declared protected in a superclass can be accessed only by the subclasses in other package or any class within the package of the protected members' class.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to call method from Frog object, at compile time it looks only for Frog class method prototype and it is declared as protected which is not visible outside Frog class.
Hope this helps you

Comment: There is no Frog object created here. Only two Tadpole objects where the second one is assigned to an object reference of type Frog...

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all of your responses. Based on some of the responses, I think I've figured out why this does not compile. I'm posting a separate response to make it completely clear and will clarify which things don't have access with respect to what since I felt that many of the responses only contained snippets of the explanation.

```
Frog f = new Tadpole();
f.ribbit(); // does not compile
```

The above does not compile because although the Tadpole object is created in the Tadpole class itself and is calling Tadpole's ribbit() method, it is called using a Frog object reference. Here we have a subclass that is assigned to a superclass reference and because of polymorphism, the Frog object reference "f" will attempt to call Tadpole's ribbit() method. However, **because ribbit() is protected and Frog is NOT a subclass of Tadpole, an object reference of type Frog cannot access a protected method defined in Tadpole.** This is why the code does not compile.

Again, this is confusing because Tadpole is a subclass of Frog and all calls are being made in the subclass Tadpole. The thing to note though is that the call itself is being made using an object reference "f" which is of type Frog that is attempting to access a protected method from Tadpole and Frog is NOT a subclass of Tadpole.

Comment: The compiler error has nothing to do with polymorphism. Polymorphism is a runtime aspect and the compiler does not "care" if `f` is actually a `Frog` or a `Tadpole` at runtime. All the compiler is doing here is enforcing the rules of the `protected` modifier, nothing more.

Comment: Not all polymorhpism are runtime but overriding is runtime polymorphism which you are trying to achieve. And you got confused about runtime polymorphism as compile time , and expected the call to be compiled properly though the method is not visible from the calling class.